# Create custom hierarchy in Menu Module

Tags: module, fix-my-code, menu

I have the following Menu Structure

```
Books [/books]
    New Books [/books/new-books]
        Fiction [/books/new-books/fiction]
        Sci Fi[/books/new-books/sci-fi]
```

The Books Menu has Books (the Menu itself) as the first level, New books as the second level and Fiction and Sci Fi as the third level.

What I am trying to achieve is the following. Essentially the url structure for the 'Sci Fi' Menu Item remains the same but visually, it sits under Fiction.

```
Books [/books]
    New Books [/books/new-books]
        Fiction [/books/new-books/fiction]
            Sci Fi[/books/new-books/sci-fi]
```

There were two ways I thought I might (a big might at that) be able to achieve this but both seems like a very 'ugly' way to go about doing it but I can't think of any other way I could achieve this.

Method 1: Created a content plugin to which will check a pre-defined class name on the  of the menu list item -> get the parent li -> remove all such menu items and put it under another predefined parent item.

Method 2: Using jQuery get all the list items with a defined class (in the jsfiddle "fourth-menu"), remove it from their existing position and add it to the pre-defined parent (using class/id on the menu item href).

As I mentioned before both method sounds very convoluated so I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve this?

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7v0dfcL/1/) which makes it a bit more clear as to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use template overrides to achieve an altered rendering, `mod_menu` is no exception. But a better way might be the use of `Menu Item Aliases`. You can find this menu item type under "System Links" if you create or modify a menu item.

A `Menu Item Alias` will use the URL of its target menu item. A possible structure could look like the following example:

```
Basic Menu, which may or may not be displayed:
- RealA (type: any) => /a
- - RealB (type: any) => /a/b
- - RealC (type: any) => /a/c

Special Menu, which will be displayed through mod_menu
- AliasC (type: alias, target: Realc) => /a/c
- - AliasA (type: alias, target: RealA) => /a
- AliasB (type: alias, target: RealB) => /a/b
```

Comment: I tried doing a test but all I see in the Module output is the level 1 Item [RealA or Books in the example I used]. I have attached the relevant [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/Wfyv1) showing I followed what you mentioned but maybe I am missing something here but it just won't show up. The only way the menu items show up is if I say 'Yes' to Show all Menu Items all the time.

Comment: That's how Joomla works. Unfortunately there is no workaround to alter the behavior (you could fork mod_menu). An alternative might be to use "Show all Menu Items" and hide items via CSS, as even aliases should have the right "active"-class.

Comment: Will give a try. I have an idea where I think I will try to add a custom field in the Menu Item ('Display Under') and allow the editors to select the 'visual parent' item. Will update the post to see if I have any luck.

Comment: Maybe this could work: https://github.com/nueckman/joomla-ex-menuaddition

Comment: Thanks Nils. Will give it a whirl this weekend and inform how it goes.